# How can you get around the bounty without paying it?

Tags: starfield

For some not yet known reason, there is a huge bounty (238'000 Credits) on my head.

How can I get around this bounty without paying it?

(Preferably without having to load a (much) earlier savegame.)

Comment: Is the PC console an option?

Comment: @LoreFriendly AFAIK, the only console command to remove your bounty involves paying it off. While making money isn't the hardest thing in the world if you want to pay it off instead, that would be a different question.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to to surrender to the appropriate authorities, whether by hailing the ship, or talking to the factions guards, and then go to jail instead of paying the bounty. You will lose any stolen goods or contraband you have on you, so you should probably store those away prior to getting yourself arrested.

According to [this site:](https://www.charlieintel.com/starfield/starfield-jail-system-explained-267765/) you will stay in jail longer, and lose more XP (should never lose a level or go below 0 XP) the higher your bounty is.

Comment: Unfortunately the bounty was from the Crimson Fleet. They don't have authorities or a jail (which would be ridiculous for a confederation of individual pirates).